# Wix WIN64DUALFOLDERS substitute issue

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I have created Wix bundle custom setup. In that we have option to select desire path to install our setup. I have noticed that when I select path "C:\Program Files\Test" and try to install then it will change path automatically and install in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test" folder. I have see log and find below error log:

MSI (s) (C0:28) [15:34:44:338]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: 'C:\Program Files (x86)' will substitute 17 characters in 'C:\Program Files\Test' folder path. (mask argument = 0, the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
MSI (s) (C0:28) [15:34:44:338]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ADDININSTALLDIR property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\Test'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Test'.

Anyone have idea how can we stop this behaviour or any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `Component` that installs in the folder is 64-bit. In WiX v3, compile the package as 64-bit or explicitly force a Component to be 64-bit by setting `Component/@Win64='yes'`.